# Istanbul and Mocha give 'Reference Error: suite is not defined' with my Node.JS project tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, istanbul

I am using Istanbul with Mocha and the Chai assertion libraries to perform unit tests and code coverage tests on a Node.js project. I am running on a Linux server which I have an account for.

I am able to run my unit tests as follows with Mocha in both the test driven development (TDD) and behavior driven development (BDD) flavors, successfully, with the following two commands:

```
./node_modules/.bin/_mocha -u tdd -R spec qa/tdd_Person.js
./node_modules/.bin/_mocha -u bdd -R spec qa/bdd_Person.js
```

I am also able to run Istanbul on a BDD test with the following code:

```
./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover --reporter=text ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha -u bdd -R spec qa/bdd_Person.js
```

But,when I try to run Istanbul with my TDD tests I get a 'Reference Error: suite is not defined' on the first instance of a suite in my tests JavaScript code:

```
./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover --reporter=text ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha -u tdd -R spec qa/tdd_Person.js
```

I also have NYC installed in my Node projects and can run both of my TDD and BDD tests perfectly fine with the following commands:

```
./node_modules/.bin/nyc --reporter=text ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha -u tdd -R spec qa/tdd_Person.js
./node_modules/.bin/nyc --reporter=text ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha -u bdd -R spec qa/bdd_Person.js
```

So why are my TDD tests failing with Istanbul but working in all other cases, yet my BDD tests work always. Is there something I am missing about Istanbul?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after all this time I discovered the answer and wanted to report back. Apparently what was missing was two dashes after mocha. Below are examples for tdd and bdd development.

Behavior Driven Development Style Tests:

```
./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover --reporter=text ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- -u bdd -R spec qa/bdd_Person.js
```

Test Driven Development Style Tests:

```
./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover --reporter=text ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- -u tdd -R spec qa/tdd_Person.js
```

It seems that the bdd style of tests are not sensitive to the omission of the two dashes, but tdd is. That makes me wonder if this is a bug or a feature.